# Correct wrong email address used to set up iCloud account

Tags: icloud, email, setup

When I initially set up my Apple iCloud account, I entered my email address incorrectly and as a result have been unable to verify.  How can I go back into my initial set up and correct the email address I gave it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please try to make your titles as explanatory as possible to explain what the actual problem is that you are facing. I have edited your title to try to summarise the problem but feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

First before doing ANYTHING, make sure to turn off find my iPhone.

Then go to https://appleid.apple.com/ and change your appleid.

Then there will be a number of places you need to log out on your phone and log back in with the correct ID. iCloud, iMessage, Facetime, game center, app store/iTunes to name most.

Then turn FindMyIphone back on.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a new one.

If you've already set the existing (wrong) account up on your devices, remove it from all of them (on one device, make sure that you select the option to keep contacts etc., on the others click delete so you don't end up with double or triple content later). Keep in mind that the account is set up in multiple places. iCloud settings itself, eventually store, iMessage, FaceTime.

Then create a new account and enter that accordingly.